# to call up owncloud with own domain name instead of Ipadress?

Tags: networking, server, apache2, owncloud-server

i am doing my final projekt and i am working on owncloud version 10 and its insatlled on ubuntu server 16.04 LTS. when i write ipadress of my ubuntu server then i can see my owncloud but now i am trying to create one Domain (without buying or register any domian from domain companies) that instead of writing ipadress i can write this domain for example 
ipadress ubuntuserver =192.168.5.169 but instead of that i would like to write some mycloud.com or myprojekt.com . When i write my hostname it works also fine thats why i also tried to make one more host name and give him server ip adress but it didnt not work. 
now my querstion is how can i tell my windows webbrowser that when i write mycloud.com than it no need to search in internet. I know there is a way to make some changes in router DNS and it will work but as i told i am doing work in projekt and i am not allowed to change anything on my uni router. My proffessor says its possible without buying any domain and make any change into router .i just want to use it within LAN not from outside LAN .Is there anyone that can help me .I would be thankfull for that

Answer (score 1):

The most basic way of handling this is just editing the "hosts" file  on the computer that's going to be looking up the domain. On an Ubuntu computer that would mean running `sudoedit /etc/hosts` and adding something like:

```
192.168.5.169   myprojekt.com
```

If you're dealing with Windows, you can find [similar instructions here](https://superuser.com/a/395276/30127). It's largely identical except you have to backflip through a burning hoop  to edit it with sufficient privileges.

You *may* also need to [tell OwnCloud](https://superuser.com/a/395276/30127) about the domain. Which *may* break other clients using the IP address. I don't use it so I'm not sure how attached OwnCloud is to a particular or whether it just uses relative links.

---

If you have more than one computer that needs to address this, **get a domain**. I know you explicitly said you didn't want to do this but I'm guessing it's a cost assumption. Some domains are free, especially if you don't need a top-level domain.

There are hundreds of organisations like [afraid.org](https://freedns.afraid.org/) that offer free subdomain direction. You sign up, plumb in your internal IP (192.168.5.169) and that should allow you to resolve it from anywhere (but it'll only connect within the LAN).

If you don't want a `something.afraid.org` domain, find another service or simply buy a domain. Most aren't expensive.

Comment: is there any suggestion .its my task from my proffessor i have to solve it like that without any domain . i know its free to have some domains. its not about cost. i must have to solve like that